# We are level one/at level one in English

Tags: word-usage

If there is  a language center that teaches different levels of English, for those who are level one, which one should they say?

1. We are level one
2. We are at level one in English

And is it correct for the teacher to say

> I usually teach the letter sounds in level one classes

Answer (score 2):

You might be:

> at level one
>
> on level one
>
> studying level one (English); in the level one group/class.

You would teach the letter sounds (phonics, phonetics):

> in THE level one class.

Or, if there were more than one level one class:

> in A level one class.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more correct to one of:

- We are studying level one English.
- We are studying English at level one.
- We are studying English Level One. *This assumes a recognised syllabus for Level One English which makes the whole of "English Level One" a proper noun*

The teacher could say:

- I usually teach the letter sounds in level one English classes
- We learn letter sounds in level one English classes
- I usually teach the letter sounds in level one Language classes
- Level One English classes commence with the letter sounds
- The letter sounds are taught in level one English classes

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about *we are at level one.* And if the subject matter of the classes is clear, *level one classes* is just as correct as *level one English classes*, and more succinct.

Comment: @PeterShor "We are at level one" without context might refer to the floor that we are on as there is no subject other than We!